Grönwall estimate: boundedness to decay
Suppose $f(t)$ is a smooth, nonnegative function defined on $[0,\infty)$. Suppose in addition that $f(t)$ satisfies the following integral inequality
$$
f(t)+M\int_0^t f(s)ds\le \delta 
$$
for all $t\ge 0$. Though I'm not sure if this will be relevant, we can further assume (if needed) that $\delta$ is a small number and $M$ is a large number. It trivially follows from this relation that $f$ satisfies the uniform bound
$$f(t)\le \delta.$$
However, due to the fact that $\int_0^t f(s)ds$ is bounded uniformly in $t$ by $\frac{\delta}{M}$, we must have that $f$ decays. My question is, can we obtain a pointwise decay estimate of the type
$$f(t)\lesssim \frac{\delta}{M}e^{-ct}?$$
This "conjecture" comes from the fact that $f(t)=\frac{\delta}{2M}e^{-t}$ is an example of a function that satisfies the above integral inequality (assuming $M\ge 1$).

For $f(t)=\varepsilon(t+1)^{-2}$ we get $$f(t)+M\int\limits_0^tf(s)\,ds\le \varepsilon (1 +M)$$ Therefore we cannot expect the exponential decay of $f(t)$ at infinity.
